# Invalid transaction with Express Checkout REST API Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I want to set up Paypal on my website but I have an issue with the Express Checkout, I followed [this integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/) but I have an error after the initiation of the payment. Here is how I define my button

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: 'sandbox', // Specify 'sandbox' for the test environment
    locale: 'fr_FR',
    style: {
        size: 'responsive',
        color: 'blue',
        shape: 'rect'
    },
    payment: function(resolve, reject) {
      var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = '/PayPalCreatePayment.php';
      paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL, {'commande': angular.toJson(commande)})
        .then(function(data){
            resolve(data.paymentID);
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            reject(err);
      });
}, '#paypal-button');
```

When I click on the generated button, it opens a lightbox with a connexion button which should open the review of the purchase and a button to execute the payment but instead I have a new window with a message :

> This transaction isn't valid, please redirect to the merchant website

I have no error code or other message. The payment code that I generate in the `CREATE_PAYMENT_URL` is valid

I've already search for this on google but I'm still stuck, how can I solve this ? Tell me if you need more explanation

Comment: Can you console log `data.paymentID` ? It should be a string, like `"PAY-XXXXXXXXXX"`

Comment: @bluepnume Well, it seems that my code work now, I changed nothing it was just a problem with Paypal